# Asp.net MVC with google drive API OAuth 2.0 not working in production

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to build a web application to open some videos I already have in a google drive.

I already have the direct links to the video, and I have a web page with a video player that takes the URL as a parameter to play it.

The issue is when I run that site from the localhost or VS2015 is working as I need, and video played with no problem. At the same time, in the production host, which is a public hosting, it keeps showing an error about can't open the google account web site to get the authentication approval.
where I am already using the FlowMetadata as by google showing here 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc

my customization was just for my scope which is drive and read-only, also I'm using the API V3 as well as I generated my credentials from the developer's console as "Other" so it didn't 
require to add a specific URL as a trusted redirect page.
my public domain was also verified 
** I already tried with generating credentials for web and with redirect url and same issue 
The error as below

```
NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A62583%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.readonly"
```

Comment: Could you please add to the question the code you're using so I can try to replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the Web Application OAuth implementation you're using, as stated in the documentation [1], you do need to add a redirect URI:

> In order to run the following code successfully, you must first add a
>   redirect URI to your project in the Google API Console

When creating the credentials from the developer's console you need to select "Web application" instead of "Other", this way it'll allow you to add the redirect URIs.

[1] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc

Comment: I didn’t mentioned that I already tested that, adding a redirect url as you mentioned and same issue and same error